# Value of label resets after the app is force quit in Swift and Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, label

I am new to Xcode and Swift programming. I am making an app that tracks water drank in a day. For some reason though, the fluid ounces (label) reset when I force quit the app (tapping red circle with minus, or swiping away app card). Is there any way I can keep the value of the label from resetting when the app is force quit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1: Store the value of the label in a persistent storage such as NSUserDefaults. Populate your ui again when you open the app.

Method 2: Use [State Restoration](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1395-state-restoration-tutorial-getting-started)